# Android - Custom calculator?

Tags: android, string, calculator, android-edittext

I am writing a custom calculator Android app. Basically, I have five edittexts, a calculate button and a reset button. I have hooked up the reset button so that onclick of the reset button it sets the value of all five edittexts to "".

How would I go about getting the values of all the edittexts on calculate button click and making an algorithm? Since there are five values, would I need to save each to a sort of temporary cache string?

I am really, really new to this so very plain english is preferable.
Thanks for any reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you're trying to calculate is a sum, then you should iterate through the Edit Texts (which you can conveniently save in an Array or a Collection... I'd rather go for the Array actually), and, well, add it to the previous value in an auxiliary variable.

I don't get where is the problem. Maybe I'm misunderstanding something. Seeing your current code could help.